# Autodesk API - Table Data

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Wondering if anyone could point us to some examples or more (better) information.

We are trying Autodesk Platform Services and have this working for our .DWG files => https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs

What we are trying to figure out is how to EXTRACT the data from tables in our DWG files.  We can see the tables in the viewer so we assume there must be a good way to get the rows and columns data.

If anyone has any advice on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The contents of Table entity are stored in `strings`, there is an associated `stringDbIds` handle value of each table entity, and `stringBoxes` with geometry information. `{stringBoxes} = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData();`

```
const {strings, stringDbIds} = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData();
const label = [];  
  strings.forEach((element, index) => {
    label.push([element]);
  }); 
  stringDbIds.forEach((element, index) => {
    label[index].push(element);
  });

//creating two dimensional array avoids skipping duplicates, renders the array as it is. :) 
console.log(label);
```

[image]